# Splitting a string based upon characters in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="mainbox">
    <button onclick="equals()"> </button>
</body>
</html>
<script src="Calculator.js"></script>
```

```
var equation = document.getElementById('mainbox').value
function equals(){
    var equationSplit = equation.split(/\+\-/);
    console.log(equationSplit)
}
```

Im trying to have the array split based upon + and - signs. I'm currently in the process of just splitting it, but it always returns array length 1.

Comment: Move `var equation = document.getElementById('mainbox').value` to the start of the function.

Comment: Your regex matches exactly `+-`, are you trying to match either symbol on its own?

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You should move the code of getting the value of the `mainbox` input value into the `equals` function, because you want the value after the button is pressed not after the JS is parsed.

```
var equation = document.getElementById('mainbox').value
```

**2)** You can use regex as `/[+-]/g`

[image]

```js
function equals() {
  var equation = document.getElementById('mainbox').value
  var equationSplit = equation.split(/[+-]/g);
  console.log(equationSplit)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="mainbox">
<button onclick="equals()">split</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex splits at the first sequence of `'+-'` which it probably doesn't find in the string.

Make the regex match either one of the characters by itself by wrapping them in `[]` and set the global flag to make it match multiple occurrences:

```js
var equationSplit = equation.split(/[\+\-]/g);
```